# execute functions in a queue

Tags: python

i have a example who should show what i'd like to do

```
queue = 2

def function():
    print 'abcd'
    time.sleep(3)

def exec_times(times):
    #do something
    function()

def exec_queue(queue):
    #do something
    function()

exec_times(3)
#things need be working while it waiting for the function finish
time.sleep(10)
```

the result should be

```
abcd
abcd

#after finish the first two function executions
abcd
```

so, there is a way to do that without use thread?

i mean some glib function to do this job.

Comment: You will need to have some sort of threading/multiprocess model to have concurrent execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid threads, one option is to use multiple processes.  If you're on python 2.6, take a look at the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module.  If python 2.5, look at [pyprocessing](http://pyprocessing.berlios.de/).

Note "[Process Pools](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool)" in the docs for multiprocessing, which seem to handle your requirements:

> One can create a pool of processes which will carry out tasks submitted to it with the Pool class.
>
> class multiprocessing.Pool([processes[, initializer[, initargs[, maxtasksperchild]]]])
>
> A process pool object which controls a pool of worker processes to which jobs 
>       can be submitted. It supports **asynchronous** results with **timeouts** and **callbacks** 
>       and has a parallel map implementation.

Comment: i am thinking something like the glib.timeout_add(interval, callback, ...) instead execute function every interval, it will keep watching the function until it finish ,then callback is called.


thanks for reply

Comment: Note that the parameter maxtasksperchild is only available in Python 2.7